# Pagination (including title of each page) in a post for a long posts

Tags: plugins, posts, navigation

I currently have pagination on my website for long posts. I have split the post into several pages.
But it only displays the page number with navigation arrows, but not a title for each page in a dropdown list.
I am attaching a picture of an example...
[image]
Is there any plugin I can use for enabling such a feature?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sgr-nextpage-titles/) to add titles and content list with links